# How do I redirect to login page if not in logged in state and after login redirect to the original page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building a website and being new to the Angular JS, I am unable to find out the way to redirect to the login page in case user is not logged in and after login to the referrer. I am using ui-router for routing.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about http interceptors

http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/